# EDL2 : $(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve this equation :
>
> $(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=0 \qquad $ on $ \left]\dfrac{1}{2},+\infty\right[$ and on $\mathbb{R}$

**Attempt :**

---

*First step :* $\varphi_1$

The first step was to find a solution in that form : $\varphi_1(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

I found $\varphi_1(x)= 4x^2+1$

---

Second step : $\varphi_2$

We consider now this equation : $y''+\dfrac{4x-2}{2x+1}y'-\dfrac{8}{2x+1}y=0$

Let $W(x)=\begin{array}{|ll|}\varphi_1(x)&\varphi_2(x)\\\varphi_1'(x)&\varphi_2'(x)\end{array}$

As we know that $W'(x)=-\dfrac{4x-2}{2x+1}W(x)$ we have got $\displaystyle W(x) =\exp\left[\int_{x_0}^x -\dfrac{4s-2}{2s+1}\cdot ds\right]=\lambda(2x+1)^2e^{-2x}$

And as $\left(\dfrac{\varphi_2(x)}{\varphi_1(x)}\right)' =\dfrac{W(x)}{(\varphi_1(x))^2}$

So now I must compute $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{W(x)}{(\varphi_1(x))^2}\cdot  dx = \int \dfrac{\lambda(2x+1)^2}{(4x^2+1)^2}\cdot e^{-2x}\cdot  dx=\gamma(x)$

Thus $\dfrac{\varphi_2(x)}{\varphi_1(x)}=\gamma(x)\iff \varphi_2(x)=\varphi_1(x)\cdot \gamma(x)$

But I can't find $\displaystyle \gamma(x)=\int \dfrac{\lambda(2x+1)^2}{(4x^2+1)^2}\cdot e^{-2x}\cdot  dx$

**May I have a hint to solve this integral**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposing $y = e^{a t}$ and substituting into the differential equation we have

$$
(2+a)(a+2a t)e^{a t} = 0\Rightarrow a+2 = 0
$$

but the differential equation is of second order so we have two conditions to satisfy and in consequence we need another independent solution.

Proposing now $y = b t^2+c t+ d$ and substituting into the differential equation we have
_0
$$
2(b-4d-c(1+2t)) = 0 \Rightarrow c = 0,  b-4d = 0 \Rightarrow y = 4t^2+1
$$

and finally the general solution is

$$
y = C_1 e^{-2t}+C_2(4t^2+1)
$$

Comment: thanks but I don't want the solution...but just how to compute the integral, and I already gave one solution $4t^2+1$

Comment: Analyzing the integral it is easy to infer $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{e^{-2t}}{2(4t^2+1)}\right) = $

Answer (score 1):

For the integral consider

$$\left(\frac {e^{-2x}}{4x^2+1}\right)'=-2e^{-2x}\frac {(2x+1)^2}{(4x^2+1)^2}$$
$$\left(\frac {e^{-2x}}{4x^2+1}\right)=-2\int e^{-2x}\frac {(2x+1)^2}{(4x^2+1)^2}dx$$
$$\phi_2=-\frac 12 e^{-2x} $$
or
$$\phi_2=e^{-2x} $$

Another look at the differential equation

$$(2x+1)y''+(4x-2)y'-8y=0 \qquad$$
$$(2x+1)(y''+2y')-4(y'+2y)=0 \qquad$$
Substitute $z=y'+2y$
$$(2x+1)z'-4z=0 \qquad$$
Which is separable and easy to integrate